# Call a method in another class

Tags: java, methods, static

I have a class called Ball, and i want to call a method called update in a class called MagicBallImage. Below is the method isVisible() in the Ball class, from which I am trying to call the method update, but I am getting an error saying:

```
Ball.java:58: non-static method update() cannot be referenced from a static context. 
MagicBallImage.update();

Ball Class

public boolean isVisible()
{
  if (magicBallState != 1)
  {
    return true;
    MagicBallImage.update();
  }
}
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: could you show us the lcass MagicBallImage

Comment: Your class is not looking healthy, will the MagicBallImage ever get called as its after the return statement. Try creating an instance of the MagicBallImage class and then call the update

Comment: btw, as there is a return statement above `MagicBallImage.update()`, `update()` will never run if magicBallState != 1. So you should shift the return statement below `MagicBallImage.update()`. Edit: Just saw shawn's comment, and I agree with him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling you that you're trying to call a non-static method without a class instance.  You either need an instance of `MagicBallImage` to call the method on, or you need to convert the method to `static`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (magicBallState != 1)
  {
    return true;
    MagicBallImage.update();
  }
```

1. you're returning before you call update, so it will have no effect
2. `update()` is not a `static method`, so you can't call it from a static context. You can simply call `update()` or `this.update()` if you're already in object scope, or call `o.update()` where `o` is your object.

Answer (score 1):

This error tells you that you cannot call update without specifying an *instance* of `MagicBallImage`.

Two things could have happened:

- You have forgotten to make the `MagicBallImage.update()` method `static`, or
- You need to make an instance of `MagicBallImage` that you created somewhere using the `new` operator available to your `isVisible()` method.

Note 1: The way it is coded now, `MagicBallImage.update()` is not accessible, because it comes after the `return` statement.

Note 2: It is very undesirable for a getter `isVisible` to have side effects, such as updating something in an instance of another class. It is a nearly 100% indication that something is wrong with your design.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call this method like this, the method has to be declared `static`. If it's not you have to declare an instance of `MagicBallImage` to access `update()`:

```
MagicBallImage mbi = new MagicBallImage();
mbi.update();
```

Comment: I tried the code you gave, but now I am getting this error:                                                                   MagicBall.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor MagicBallImage()
location: class MagicBallImage
      MagicBallImage mbi = new MagicBallImage();

Comment: Mmmh what does your MagicBallImage constructor look like?

Comment: public MagicBallImage(MagicBall paramMagicBall)
  {
    super(paramMagicBall);
    this.magicBall = paramMagicBall;

    addMouseListener(this);}

Comment: you need to declare a new MagicBallImage in the form `MagicBallImage mbi = new MagicBallImage(MagicBall ball);`

Comment: Then you have to pass a MagicBall as argument to your constructor (maybe `this`?).

Comment: @talnicolas I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: if you try `MagicBallImage mbi = new MagicBallImage(this); mbi.update();`, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Make the update() method static or create a instance of MagicBallImage and call update()